# Linux - how to add onedrive as service and start automatically

Tags: linux, onedrive

I am trying to add onedrive as a service in a linux machine but when I prompt the following command:

```
systemctl --user enable onedrive
```

I got this error:

```
Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=<user>@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)
```

Has anyone faced this error before?

thanks